# Spring Boot Bean creation Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting the below inconsistent exception while starting spring boot service.This error not occurs every time I start the service.Sometime I am able to start it after 4 or 5 attempts sometimes it does not give the exception and it starts in first attempt.

I will appreciate if any one can provide me some solution.

***INJECTING ChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter...****
    ***INJECTING ChangeRecordDaoAdapter...****
    ***INJECTING NotificationHelper...****
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'changeRecordService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.IChangeRecordAdapter com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.ChangeRecordService.iChangeRecordAdapter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectChangeRecordDaoAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.notificationHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectNotificationHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at com.att.vtm.Application.main(Application.java:53)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.IChangeRecordAdapter com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.ChangeRecordService.iChangeRecordAdapter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectChangeRecordDaoAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.notificationHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectNotificationHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectChangeRecordDaoAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.notificationHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectNotificationHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.notificationHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectNotificationHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectNotificationHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper.userUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 51 more
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/app/workload/vtm_services/deployment/change_record/changerecord-service-1.0.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/app/workload/vtm_services/deployment/change_record/changerecord-service-1.0.jar!/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

Comment: Please edit your question after reading [mcve] and format your log using markdown .  You will probably get help faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right there: `Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings`.
Please revise your dependencies. You seem to have 2 or more SLF4J libraries on you classpath.